# How to use SDL2 Texture as sort of updating canvas?

Tags: c++, textures, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to create a dynamic plotter in SDL2 for an embedded project. Currently, the code executes on both architectures, x86, and ARM. On x86 I get a smooth running plotter, however, on ARM it runs very slow at a fraction of the frames I get on x86. I am pretty sure this is because I rerender every pixel on the surface at this is a massive overheat on the embedded device.

I tried rendering the new content to a texture, copy it to the renderer and then render, but this did not work at all.

Due to the double-buffering, I have to clear every frame. Otherwise, I will "drop" changes. But I also need to render the old data points and only overwrite them when the plotter reaches them again.

Is there a way in SDL2 to save these data points to some sort of canvas and only add (redraw) the newly added ones?

Heres my source code:

**Plotter.cpp**

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "PlotterHelper.h"

/*Implementation*/
int main(int arhc, char * argv[])
{
    //Top and bottom viewport
    SDL_Rect topViewport;
    SDL_Rect bottomViewport;
    topViewport = CreateViewPort(0,0, SCREEN_WIDTH, (SCREEN_HEIGHT/2));
    bottomViewport = CreateViewPort(0,(SCREEN_HEIGHT/2), SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2);

    float timeFrame = 4.0;
    int updateWidth = round(SCREEN_WIDTH/(60.0 * timeFrame));


    uint8_t backgroundColor = 0xff;

    int delayTime = 0;
    int sinusScale = 0;
    int rectWidth = RECT_WIDTH;
    bool rectEnd = false;

    SDL_Point points[SCREEN_WIDTH] = {0,0};
    int pointPosition = 0;

    if (!init())
    {
        printf("Init failed!\n");
    }
    else
    {

        SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);
        //Main lopp flag
        bool quit = false;
        //Event handler
        SDL_Event event;

        //While application is running
        while(!quit)
        {
            //Handle events on queue
            while (SDL_PollEvent( &event) != 0)
            {
                //User requests quit
                if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
                else if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                {
                    switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                    {
                    case SDLK_w:
                        delayTime += 50;
                        if(delayTime > 5000)
                            delayTime = 5000;
                        break;
                    case SDLK_s:
                        delayTime -= 50;
                        if(delayTime < 0)
                            delayTime = 0;
                        break;
                    case SDLK_d:
                        timeFrame -= 1;
                        if(timeFrame < 1)
                            timeFrame = 1.0;
                        updateWidth = round(SCREEN_WIDTH/(60.0 * timeFrame));
                        printf("timeFrame = %lf\n", timeFrame);
                        break;
                    case SDLK_a:
                        timeFrame += 1;
                        if(timeFrame > 44)
                            timeFrame = 44.0;
                        updateWidth = round(SCREEN_WIDTH/(60.0 * timeFrame));
                        printf("timeFrame = %lf\n", timeFrame);
                        break;
                    case SDLK_r:
                        if(backgroundColor == 0x3f)
                            break;
                        else
                        {
                            ++backgroundColor;
                            break;
                        }
                    case SDLK_f:
                        if(backgroundColor == 0x00)
                                break;
                        else
                        {
                            --backgroundColor;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Reset Plotter when the end of the window was reached
            if(pointPosition > SCREEN_WIDTH-1)
            {
                pointPosition = 0;
                sinusScale = (rand() % 100 + 1) - 50;
                rectWidth = RECT_WIDTH;
                rectEnd = false;
            }

            //Handler eraser when he reaches end of window
            if(((SCREEN_WIDTH-1) - pointPosition) < RECT_WIDTH)
            {
                rectWidth = (SCREEN_WIDTH -1) - pointPosition;
                rectEnd = true;

            }


            //Clear screen
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, backgroundColor, backgroundColor, backgroundColor, 0xff);
            SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);


            //Draw top viewport
            SDL_RenderSetViewport( gRenderer, &topViewport );

            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x00, 0x66, 0x00, 0xff);
            for(int iterator = 0; iterator <= SCREEN_WIDTH -1; ++iterator)
            {
                SDL_RenderDrawLine(
                        gRenderer,
                        points[iterator].x,
                        0,
                        points[iterator].x,
                        SCREEN_HEIGHT/2);
            }

            PlotEraser(rectEnd, backgroundColor, rectWidth,points[pointPosition].x );

            //raw bottom viewport
            SDL_RenderSetViewport( gRenderer, &bottomViewport );

            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x00, 0x66, 0x00, 0xff);
            for(int iterator = 0; iterator <= SCREEN_WIDTH -1; ++iterator)
                {
                    SDL_RenderDrawLine(
                            gRenderer,
                            points[iterator].x,
                            SCREEN_HEIGHT/2,
                            points[iterator].x,
                            points[iterator].y);
                }

            PlotEraser(rectEnd, backgroundColor, rectWidth,points[pointPosition].x );


            for(int iterator = pointPosition; iterator <= pointPosition + updateWidth; ++iterator)
            {
                points[iterator].x = iterator;
                points[iterator].y = round(((SCREEN_HEIGHT/4 )* sin(iterator/(100.0+sinusScale))) + SCREEN_HEIGHT/4);
            }
            pointPosition += updateWidth;

            //Update Screen
            SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);

            SDL_Delay(delayTime);
        }

    }

    //Free resources and close SDL
    close();

    return 0;
}

/*End of File*/
```

**PlotterHelper.cpp**

```
/*Includes*/

#include "PlotterHelper.h"

SDL_Window  * gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Renderer * gRenderer = NULL;
SDL_Renderer * intermediate = NULL;

/*Implementation*/

/*********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
*/
bool init()
{
    //Init  flag
    bool success = true;

    //Init SDL
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Set texture filtering to linear
        if( !SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1" ) )
        {
            printf( "Warning: Linear texture filtering not enabled!" );
        }

        //Set VSYNC
        if( !SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC, "1" ) )
        {
            printf( "Warning: VSYNC not enabled!" );
        }

        //Create window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(
                "SDL Plotter",
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SCREEN_WIDTH,
                SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if (NULL == gWindow)
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Create renderer for window
            gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );
            if(NULL == gRenderer)
            {
                printf("Renderer could not be created! SDLError: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Initialise renderer colour
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);
            }

        }
    }
    return success;
}

/*********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
*/
void close()
{
    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gRenderer = NULL;
    gWindow = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
}

/*********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
*/

SDL_Rect CreateViewPort(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    SDL_Rect Viewport;
    Viewport.x = x;
    Viewport.y = y;
    Viewport.w = w;
    Viewport.h = h;

    return Viewport;
}
/*********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
*/
void PlotEraser(bool rectEnd, uint8_t backgroundColor, int rectWidth, int x)
{
    SDL_Rect fillRectBot = {x, 0, rectWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2};

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, backgroundColor, backgroundColor, backgroundColor, 0xff);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &fillRectBot);

    if(rectEnd)
    {
        int startRecWidth = RECT_WIDTH - rectWidth;

        SDL_Rect startRec = {0, 0, startRecWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2};
        SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &startRec);
    }
}

/*End of File*/
```

**PlotterHelper.h**

```
#ifndef PLOTTER_HELPER_H_
#define PLOTTER_HELPER_H_

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
/*Globals*/

//Screen  constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1024;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 768;
const int RECT_WIDTH = 10;

//The window we'll be rendering to
extern SDL_Window * gWindow;
//The window renderer
extern SDL_Renderer * gRenderer;
extern SDL_Renderer * intermediate;


/*Prototypes*/
/*********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
*/
//Starts up SDL and creates window
bool init();
/*********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
*/
//Free media and shut down SDL
void close();
/*********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
*/
//CreateVieport
SDL_Rect CreateViewPort(int x, int y, int w, int h);
/*********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
 *********************************************************************
*/
//Plot Eraser
void PlotEraser(bool rectEnd, uint8_t backgroundColor, int rectWidth, int x);
#endif /* PLOTTER_HELPER_H_ */
/*End of File*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a couple of options that can help:

## Use a texture render target

You ought to be able to accomplish this using a "render target texture". That is an `SDL_Texture` you create (see `SDL_CreateTexture`) with the `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET` flag.

You would draw new points to this texture by calling `SDL_SetRenderTarget` and passing this texture before then rendering the points.

your main loop would then need to call `SDL_SetRenderTarget` and pass `nullptr` to restore the window as the rendering target. You then render your texture to the window every frame.

The [SDL documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTexture) has a small sample demoing how to use a render target texture.

## update to SDL 2.0.9 and use render batching

the latest version of SDL 2 supports render batching if you set `SDL_HINT_RENDER_BATCHING` (`SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_BATCHING, "1");`). You should use `SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer()` to ensure you have batching enabled.

This may not do anything if your platform doesnt support hardware acceleration. You can use this in conjunction with a render target. read about SDL render batching [here](https://www.patreon.com/posts/project-sdl-21856507).

## Batch your rects/points together

This is separate from render batching and should work on any version of SDL 2.

If you can, collect all your rectangles/points together in an array you can use
`SDL_RenderDrawPoints` or `SDL_RenderDrawRects` to have SDL do them all at once which should improve performance even if you have no hardware acceleration. This can be used in conjunction with a render target.

## Ditch SDL_Renderer/SDL_Texture

If your device lacks hardware acceleration, then it might be faster to ditch SDL_Renderer and instead use `SDL_GetWindowSurface` to get the `SDL_Surface` for the window and use `SDL_BlitSurface` (or manually set pixels via `surface->pixels`) to draw directly to that then update the window with `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface`. See also `SDL_UpdateWindowSurfaceRects` for how to only update the rectangles you are changing for even better performance.

You will need to [familiarize yourself](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface) with `SDL_Surface` as you will need to inspect the pixel format of the window surface in order to update it correctly should you choose to directly manipulate the pixels.

Comment: I already tried this attempt, I was dropping frames this way.

Comment: @J.Panek If you tried a render texture why did you not say so in your question? I will update my answer with an alternative for software rendering directly to the window, but I dont know if it would actually help performance.

Comment: @J.Panek you could also try disabling vsync. does that help?

Comment: @J.Panek updated answer with a couple of other ideas. if you can batch your drawing that should help a noticeable amount.

Comment: In the question I wrote about my attempt on a render texture: _I tried rendering the new content to a texture, copy it to the renderer and then render, but this did not work at all_, maybe I expressed myself badly here. Your answer helped me a lot, Thank you for that, now only tearing issues remain.

Comment: @J.Panek you are welcome. Sorry for the confusion. You may want to look into some of the batching concepts to increase performance further. If you have tearing it sounds like probably you need vsync, but that will be a performance penalty.

Comment: I think batching is only available in 2.0.10 (not 2.0.9) which is now in pre-release.